# Question about uniform continuous proof.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

If $f(x)$ define as: $f(x) = x\cos(\log(x))$, when $x  > 0$. $f(x) = 0$, when $x = 0$.
How we prove that $f$ is uniform continuous in $[0, +\infty[$?

Comment: Take a derivative.

Comment: please use MathJax for the future: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: You can prove that it is Lipschitz continuous by showing that it's continuous at $0$ and that its derivative is bounded on $(0,\infty)$.

Answer (score 2):

$ f $ is continuous at $ x=0$ since

$$(\forall x>0)\;|f(x)|\le |x|$$

$ f $ is differentiable at $ (0,+\infty) $ and

$$(\forall x>0)\;$$
$$f'(x)=\cos(\ln(x))-\sin(\ln(x))$$

thus
$$(\forall x>0)\;\;|f'(x)|\le 2$$

So, By MVT,
$$(\forall x,y\ge0)\;\;(\exists c>0) \;\;:$$
$$|f(x)-f(y)|=|x-y||f'(c)|$$
$$\le 2|x-y|$$

$ f $ is then UC at $ [0,+\infty)$.
You just can take $ \delta=\frac{\epsilon}{2}$.

Comment: so is |f(x)-f(y)| ≤ 2|x-y| ≤ δ = ϵ right?

Comment: oh, is |f(x)-f(y)| ≤ 2|x-y| ≤ 2δ = ϵ right?