# Uniform continuous proof.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

If $f(x)$ define as: $f(x)=x\cos(\log(x))$, when $x>0$. $f(x)=0$, when $x=0$. we need prove that f is uniform continuous in $[0,+∞]$?

I already prove the following equation
$|f(x)−f(y)|=|x−y||f′(c)| ≤2|x−y|$.
I just feel confuse with the  $δ=ϵ$ conclusion and how to write it.

Comment: In this post they have already responded.  try not to repeat questions https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3905171/question-about-uniform-continuous-proof

Comment: And please use MathJax

Answer (score 2):

You only need to to complete the last step:

For every $\epsilon>0$, we may set $\delta=\epsilon/2$. As we can see, if $|x-y|<\delta$, then $$|f(x)-f(y)|\leq 2|x-y|<2\delta=2\cdot\frac{\epsilon}{2}=\epsilon.$$

Comment: Thanks! so helpful!